# Command line arguments

Tags: c, dynamic, static

I know the difference between static and dynamic memory allocation. I also know to use static when variable is of a determinable length at compile time and to use dynamic allocation when a variable is of indeterminable length at runtime.However, where do command line arguments fall in this spectrum. I have already compiled my c code into machine code, and I run the code with ./a.out . I could always declare a variable like so:  int array[n]. For a small piece of software does it matter whether I statically declare the array  or dynamically declare the array : double *array = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double)) ?

Comment: The `argv` array is already allocated for you before the program starts, it's handled automatically by the C runtime. What array are you talking about?

Comment: The title and the introductory text don't match the question you ask in the end. So what do you want to know or achieve actually?

Answer (score 0):

By default you would use something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
...
}
```

Command line arguments are stored in a char array called `argv` it's length is an integer called `argc`. `Argv[0]` is the program name. Everything after that are the command line arguments.

I suggest you explore the documentation, if you want to learn more.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function